# How can I resize Print Dialog Box when calling window.print()?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the Print Dialog Box to take 100% width and 100% height of the available screen size.

Comment: You should read [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print).

Comment: you can't. because it's browser functionality

Comment: @PhilippSander That's a shame. I hoped there's some workaround to make it work.

Comment: no. there is no workaround.